# Generate a grid of random coordinates

Tags: python, random, coordinates

I want to generate a set of 16 (x,y) coordinates in a 4x4 square grid, such that for each (x,y) the nearest neighbour distance is 1.1m.

I have tried :

```
rad=1 

ranx=(0,4)

rany=(0,4)

randPts=[]

for i in range(0,15):

    for j in range(i+1,16):

        x=random.randrange(*ranx)
        y=random.randrange(*rany)
        if (np.sqrt(((x[i]-x[j])**2)+((y[i]-y[j])**2)) != 1.1):
            randPts.append((x,y))
```

This is giving me the error : `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`
Can anyone kindly suggest how I can generate the required (x,y) grid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: randrange gives back an Int, not a list. So what are you trying to achieve with x[i]?

Comment: What kind of distance do you consider? Do you mean exactly `1.1` distance? At least? At most?

Comment: plus you've provided incomplete code, what are `qty, ranx, rany`.

Comment: I don't think your appraoch will work very well here. It might be better to first generate 16 random points, and then randomly re-arrange individual points until the min distance is 1.1

Comment: @sentence I need the points to be exactly separated by 1.1 m.

Comment: @tobias_k could you kindly elaborate on the random re-arrangement of the points part?

Comment: @AndrewAllen I have edited the code. Thanks for pointing out the typos.

Comment: Another clarification: You are looking for points on a _grid_, i.e. just integer values, so that constraint "distance at least 1.1" translates to "no points in adjacent positions, right? But on a 4x4 grid, 16 points would mean _each_ point, i.e. distances of 1 between points. Or can points lie in between lines in the grid, i.e. floating-point values? That way you might fit in a few more, but probably not 16.

Comment: It cannot be done - with grid size of 1, distance cannot be exactly 1.1m. Could be 1, or sqrt(2) or sqrt(5), but not 1.1